# Almost complex manifold but not complex

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I am looking for some examples of almost complex manifolds but not complex rather than $S^6$

Comment: A better worded question of the above form has been answered in [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/52960/which-almost-complex-manifolds-admit-a-complex-structure)